# Difference between "sudo su root" and "sudo su - root"

Tags: root

Is there any difference between "sudo su root" and "sudo su - root" ? I know `-` make the shell a login shell but what difference does it make ? Does the permission varies among them or any change in environment variable happens ?

Answer (score 3):

Login shells run `~/.profile` (or the shell-specific equivalent:  `.login` for `*csh`, `.bash_profile`, `.zshprofile`, etc.).  Without the `-`, only a shell-specific interactive config will be run (`.cshrc`, `.bashrc`, `.zshenv`; *nothing* for `ash` or derivatives thereof, or for `ksh` unless `$ENV` is set properly *and* `sudo` propagates it).  Also note that `sudo` can be configured as to how it sets `$HOME`, which determines whether it's the target account's dotfiles or your own that are used (Debian derivatives use the former, OS X the latter by default) — but using `su` along with it will override this to the target account in all cases.